# How can I enable foreign-key checks in pytest using sqllite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pytest

I have a django project with tests that run when I call `py.test`, but I've noticed recently that it isn't checking foreign key constraints. How can I get it to check foreign key constraints?

Apparently, [foreign key constraints weren't even possible until sqlite 3](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), but I don't really know what version I'm running, because I don't have a cli for sqlite, but it's just being included automatically by django? (I'm using django 1.9.10), but sqlite 3 came out in 2009, so that's not the issue right?

Perhaps [it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the PRAGMA foreign_keys command.](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), but I don't know how to make my tests do that?

[UPDATE]
So, it looks like sqlite out of the box isn't checking them.

```
class Referenced(models.Model):
    pass

class Referencer(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Referenced)

>>> Referencer.objects.create(fk_id=-1)
<Referencer>
>>> Referencer.objects.all()[0].fk
DoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a package to solve this problem.

```
pip install sqlite_checkforeignkeys
```

then configure database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlite_checkforeignkeys_engine',
        'TEST': {'NAME': ':memory:'},
    }
}
```

It involved rewriting the existing sqlite engine to enforce foreign keys

More information can be found at https://github.com/hulu/sqlite_checkforeignkeys

Answer (score 0):

Python ships with sqlite3. You may check the version by

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

As for setting the PRAGMA statement, it may depend on the driver used, and wheter you are using an ORM.

With [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/), you many use

```
db = SqliteDatabase('my_app.db', pragmas=(('foreign_keys', 'on')))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work even in unittest (manage.py test) but according to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11665 it should work.

django sqlite driver uses deferred constraints checking by default, which means constraints are checked in db commit, which never happens in tests. The ticket above should have fixed it, but apparently doesn't.

I filed a new bug for it: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29928

However, django 2 checks foreign keys for sqlite outside of tests, for example in `./manage.py shell`