# Deletion of an object in SQLite3 outputs a different error than Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite, pytest-django

I have a `Django` and `pytest-django` project and I'm encountering a weird issue. My prod env has a `Postgres` DB and when running local tests I use `SQLite3`.

Our DB schema look like this

```
class A(BaseModel):
# Some properties

class B(BaseModel):
a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=DO_NOTHING, null=False)
# Some other properties
```

Assuming I have 2 objects (`a` which is an instance of `A`, and `b` which is an instance of `B`), deleting object `a` before deleting `b` will raise the following error on `Postgres`:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table \"db_a\" violates 
foreign key constraint \"db_a_id_32c056c8_fk\" on table \"db_b\"
```

However, running the same code locally, using the ([in-memory version of](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#s-std:setting-TEST_NAME)) SQLite, will raise:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'db_b' with primary 
key '453c667321254983915068259f6a999f' has an invalid foreign key: 
db_b.a_id contains a value 'b8fd641710be466ca8eab451faaed757' that does not 
have a corresponding value in db_a.id.
```

So, in both cases, the deletion operation will output an error - but not the same one.

I have no issues with the fact that an error is raised, but I would like my local unit tests to have the same error outputted as my remote one without changing the DB locally to PG.

Any insights into this behaviour, or ideas on how to get consistent results will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

I've looked at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194777/4890123 but the errors remained the same.

Comment: I think those are DB-level errors, so in the unit tests, asserting `IntegrityError` is raised should be enough IMO

Comment: You have fallen into the **Complete Fallacy** that SQL based database systems are interchangeable.  As you proceed you will find that a difference in error message text is the least of your problems. Especially when you code works great in dev but utterly fails in prod. If you are lucky the prod version will generate and error if not who knows what it will do. That is why testing deeds to be on the same dbms that prod will reside.  Postgres is fully open source so download and install it locally.

Comment: Thanks @Belayer.. this is actually kind of what I needed to hear. I wanted to make sure that this is the reason and not some `Django` magic...